# Backing to a form with a chosen dropdown forgets its value visually

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-chosen

Using the chosen lib I run into the following issue, you can reproduce it yourself by going to their show-and-tell-page:

https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Steps to reproduce:

1. In their standard select section, select -any country you want- in both the standard dropdown and the chosen dropdown
2. Click 'fork on github'(or any link) to leave the page
3. Navigate back by hitting the back button in chrome
4. The standard dropdown shows you the previously selected country
5. The chosen dropdown is empty (but under the hood the value is selected, according to what I'm seeing with my form. It just is not showing)

So this leads to confusion. When the user would back and then go forward again by submitting the form(in my case) it would use another value than what is shown.

My form basically looks like:

```
<form id="myForm" action="${home}mySite/foo/bar" method="GET">

    <select id="bar" name="barName" class="chosen-select">
        <option value="a">foo 1</option>
        <option value="b">foo 2</option>
        <option value="c">foo 3</option>
        <option value="d">foo 4</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Continue"/>

</form>
```

If I remove the `class="chosen-select"` it works as I expect, but I lose chosen's nice search feature which I want. I've tried messing around with

`<option value="a" selected="selected">Foo 1</option>`

in the dropdown, but that doesn't help.

I've also tried changing the `method="GET"` to `POST` but there is no difference in behaviour. It still works as in the example link I provided.

The chosen lib generates the following in on the page:

```
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" title="" id="parkingZoneOwner_chosen" style="width: 40%;"><a class="chosen-single">
  <span>Foo 1</span>
  <div><b></b></div>
</a>
<div class="chosen-drop">
  <div class="chosen-search">
    <input class="chosen-search-input" type="text" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <ul class="chosen-results"></ul>
</div></div>
```

But nothing about the generated html looks wrong to me, even after backing to the page.

I tried this in the js ([events](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".chosen-select").chosen({
            width: "40%",
            search_contains: true
        });


        $('.chosen-select').on('chosen:ready', function(evt, params) {
            $(".chosen-select").val("a");
        });

    });
});


$('.chosen-select').on('chosen:ready', function(evt, params) {
    // alert("reached")
    // I had really high hopes for this one:
    $('.chosen-select').trigger('chosen:updated');

    //Also tried this one:
    $('#myForm')[0].reset();
});
```

Anyone know a way to fix this? Either the chosen dropdown needs to show what actually will be submitted in the form or the entire form maybe could be reset to default values somehow.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor HERE at Stackoverflow

Comment: @mplungjan that snippet editor was pretty rad. But I can't seem to get the chosen lib into it. I tried dl'ing the sources and pasting it manually but no, it needs something which I'm not giving it.

Comment: Ok got it to work in the snippet editor. I can not reproduce the bug in the snippet editor. But I'm not sure it is representative, you cannot really leave the page and come back to the page. (Also cannot post it here since i pasted the entire js/css of the lib in the snippet and it is too big)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved it in the end, turning off autocomplete on the form.

```
<form id="myForm" action="${home}mySite/foo/bar" autocomplete="off" method="GET">
```

I don't know why this works.

Comment: You could also set autocomplete="off" on the select itself and it should work just fine. I think it works because it tells it to not remember the selection.